# Android TextView Visibility in AlertDialog does not change

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I am using an **AlertDialog** created using android.suport.v7.app.AlertDialog and I am having a custom layout for the `Dialog` with a few EditTexts and a few TextViews.

The TextViews that are used are initially having their visibility set to `GONE`.

I am using the TextViews mainly to prompt the user for incorrect inputs in the EditText fields.

So when I try to toggle the visibility of the `TextView` to `VISIBLE` for showing an error message, the visibility does not change.

My XML File for `layoutS` is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/sampark_naam"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_name_error"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `AlertDialog` used is:

```
final Context context = view.getContext();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View aDrishya = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutS, null, false);
vNaam = (EditText) aDrishya.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
nameError = (TextView) aDrishya.findViewById(R.id.noName);
sSanddok = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                          .setView(aDrishya)
                          .setTitle("Add A New Contact")
                          .setPositiveButton("Add +", new PositiveButton(context))
                          .setNegativeButton("Pick", new null);
sSanddok.show();
```

In the positive button I check for the contactName entered as:

```
if(vNaam.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    nameError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    nameError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

It is showing the `Toast` but it's not showing the `TextView`.

Any idea what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you animate them? And do post some code please

Comment: Maybe the way you are getting the reference to the TextView, please post your code.

Comment: @UdiI No animation used

Comment: @MateusBrandao I have posted my code, do check if the TextView has been referenced properly

Comment: Does LogCat say something?

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try to change and run this code, See if it works..

### Alert dialog changes :

```
sSanddok = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                          .setView(R.layout.layoutS)
                          .setTitle("Add A New Contact")
                          .setPositiveButton("Add +", null)
                          .setNegativeButton("Pick",null);

sSanddok.show();



sSanddok.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //if edit text value is empty do this  
        TextView tv = (TextView)sSanddok.findViewById(R.id.noName);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

TextView visibility in xml is set to gone..
Hi this is working for me...Try this code pls

Comment: The reference done in the code above in the question seems to be correct as the edittext works fine.

Comment: @PSKapadia hi i edited my answer can you copy paste and try to run this code..it is working for me.

Comment: @PSKapadia hi did you copy paste the entire code and run it ? Can you share your code ? I'll try to fix it..

Comment: Used Textwatcher for the edittext instead, worked fine :)

Comment: @PSKapadia okk..happy android coding :)